# Doubt in solving the initail value problem $2x\frac{dy}{dx}=3(2y-1),y(0)=\frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The initial value problem $2x\frac{dy}{dx}=3(2y-1),y(0)=\frac{1}{2}$ has

(a) unique solution

(b) more than one but finitely many solutions

(c) Infinitely many solutions

(d) no solutions

If I solve $2x\frac{dy}{dx}=3(2y-1),y(0)=\frac{1}{2}$ the equations using variable seperable, I get $\log \frac{|2y-1|}{|x^3|}=c$ implies $e^c=\frac{2y-1}{x^3}$ but how should I move further. Cannot use $y(0)=\frac{1}{2}$ to obtain $c$, it will require to put zero in the denominator.

How should I move further?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hint: Throw caution to the wind. Try to get $y$ by itself and see what happens (it may even help to relabel $e^c = C$ because, well, a constant to a constant is a constant).

Comment: Can you not just apply [Picard theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20specifically%20the%20study,the%20existence%20and%20uniqueness%20theorem.) ?

Comment: @Nasser : No, that is not possible in this case, as the initial point is outside the domain of the ODE (the open set where $f$ from $y'=f(x,y)$ is at least continuous in $x,y$).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Rearranging your solution (and denoting $C := e^c$) yields the functions
$$y_C(x) = \frac{1}{2} + C x^3.$$ Even though the intermediate computation only applied to $x \neq 0$, we can check by substitution which $y_C(x)$, regarded as functions defined on all of $\Bbb R$, are solutions to the initial value problem. (In particular, what happens to $C$ when you impose the initial value condition?)

Comment: for any value of $c$, the initial condition will be satisfied. So $c$ can take any value. So infinitely many solutions..?

Comment: Yes. In fact, in the original solution, the equation implies $\pm e^c = \ldots$, not just $e^c = \ldots$, so $C$ can take on at least any nonzero value. Substituting shows that $C = 0$ also gives a (constant) solution. This solution disappeared early in the computation: When separating the variables, we divided by $2 y - 1$, which assumes that $y \neq \frac{1}{2}$ for any point in the domain of the solution. This behavior is typical of equations equivalent under a change of variables to the equation $x^k \frac{dy}{dx} = m x$, where $k$ is a positive integer and $m \in \Bbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\;x\neq0\,,\;$ the differential equation $\;2x\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=3(2y-1)\;$ is equivalent to each of the following ones :

$2x^4\left[\dfrac{\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}}{x^3}-\dfrac{3\left(y-\frac12\right)}{x^4}\right]=0\;\;,$

$2x^4\left[\dfrac{x^3\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}-3x^2\left(y-\frac12\right)}{x^6}\right]=0\;\;,$

$2x^4\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\dfrac{y-\frac12}{x^3}\right)=0\;\;,$

$\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\dfrac{y-\frac12}{x^3}\right)=0\;\;,$

$\dfrac{y-\frac12}{x^3}=C\;\;,\quad$ where $\;C\in\Bbb R\;,$

$y=\dfrac12+Cx^3\;.$

Now we can verify that each function , $\;y_C(x)=\dfrac12+Cx^3\;$, regarded as a function defined on $\,(-\infty,+\infty)\,,\,$ is a solution to the initial value problem, indeed ,

for any $\,C\in\Bbb R\,,\,$ it results that

$\begin{align}2x\dfrac{\mathrm dy_C}{\mathrm dx}&=2x\!\cdot\!3Cx^2=3\left(2Cx^3\right)=3\left[2\left(\dfrac12+Cx^3\right)-1\right]=\\[3pt]&=3\left(2y_C-1\right)\;,\end{align}$

$y_C(0)=\dfrac12\,.$

Consequently, the initial value problem has infinitely many solutions.